# how do i get a variables cell location and edit it

Tags: javascript, set, var

i am trying to write a script that will read the location of a cell from the variable it is linked to in script, then highlight that cell. The variable is "ASAp"

here is  an example of what I'm trying to do, highlighting the ASAp variables...

```
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) 
{ 
 var ASAp = ASAP_val[i][0];
 var days_left = days_left_values[i][0];

 if (ASAp == "ASAP"||ASAp == "asap"||ASAp == "ASAp"||ASAp == "ASap")
 {

     var reminder_name = reminder_info_values[i][0];
     var the_requester = requster[i][0]; 

   //set the active cell to be the cell that contains the word ASAP, asap, ASAp, ASap
   //then change the background color of that cell to yellow
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().setActiveSelection('ASAp').setBackground("yellow");
```

if this is not possible, or its to hard to understand what im asking then...

i am trying to write a script that will read an entire sheet for cell formated as a date "m/d/yyyy" or a word, and highlight the dates or word in the sheet.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: java script, its for a google script.